# Effective ways to group things into list

Tags: python-3.x, unsupervised-learning

I am doing a K-means project and I have to do it by hand, which is why I am trying to figure out what is the best ways to group things according to their last values into a list or a dictionary. Here is what I am talking about

```
list_of_tuples = [(honey,1),(bee,2),(tree,5),(flower,2),(computer,5),(key,1)]
```

Now my ultimate goal is to be able to sort out the list and have 3 different lists each with its respected element

```
"""This is the goal"""
list_1 = [honey,key]
list_2 = [bee,flower]
list_3 = [tree, computer]
```

I can use a lot of if statements and a for loop, but is there a more efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not opposed to using something like `pandas`, you could do something along these lines:

```
import pandas as pd

list_1, list_2, list_3 = pd.DataFrame(list_of_tuples).groupby(1)[0].apply(list).values
```

Result:

```
In [19]: list_1                                                                                           
Out[19]: ['honey', 'key']

In [20]: list_2                                                                                           
Out[20]: ['bee', 'flower']

In [21]: list_3                                                                                           
Out[21]: ['tree', 'computer']
```

**Explanation**:

`pd.DataFrame(list_of_tuples).groupby(1)` groups your list of tuples by the value at index `1`, then you extract the values as lists of index `0` with `[0].apply(list).values`. This gives you an array of lists as below:

```
array([list(['honey', 'key']), list(['bee', 'flower']),
       list(['tree', 'computer'])], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something to the effect can be achieved with a dictionary and a for loop, using the second element of the tuple as a key value.

```
list_of_tuples = [("honey",1),("bee",2),("tree",5),("flower",2),("computer",5),("key",1)]
dict_list = {}
for t in list_of_tuples:
    # create key and a single element list if key doesn't exist yet
    # append to existing list otherwise
    if t[1] not in dict_list.keys():
        dict_list[t[1]] = [t[0]]
    else:
        dict_list[t[1]].append( t[0] )
list_1, list_2, list_3 = dict_list.values()
```

Comment: I have tried using this, but there is an error that 'str' object has no attribute append. I checked, and the difference between by original code and this 'fake' one is that, in the original code, it uses int64 instead of traditional int. Can you help?

Comment: The `append()` method should be called for a *List* value inside `dict_list`, not a String. Double-check the line in our if statement. Did you assign the value as `[t[0]]`? The outside brackets are important as they tell Python that you're assigning a single element *List* to the key-value instead of a String object.